# How to serialize a single model instance AND include the primary key

Tags: python, django, serialization

I have a single model instance `obj`. I want to serialize it, and for the primary key to be included in the serialized data.

- `django.core.serializers.serializer` wants a queryset (throws an
  error that `ojb` isn't iterable).
- I simply cannot coerce
  `django.forms.model_to_dict` into including    the primary key in the
  serialized object, even explicitly calling: `model_to_dict(obj,
  fields=['pk'])` or `model_to_dict(obj, fields=['id'])`

How do I do this?

Comment: I would highly recommend this library for such cases: [Django REST Framework - Serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Comment: DRF is really overkill for what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model_to_dict` will not dump fields that have `editable=False` (so, for example, the primary key). It is possible to manually construct the object serialization by:

```
{field.name: field.value_from_object(obj) for field in obj._meta.fields}
```